# Django: I get: Cannot query "admin": Must be "Follow" instance in my code when trying to implement unfollow button

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to create a small network project in which users can follow each other. I have implemented the follow button right, so it updates my models and displays proper info to users, but I can't get unfollow to work properly. I'm guessing it's something to do with the way I implemented follow model (with many to many field), but I'd like to implement it this way for practice... Anyhow, here's the code:

Models:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
class Follow(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_follow")
    following = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name="followers")
```

And view:

```
def users(request, username):
    """Displaying user profiles"""

    if request.method == "POST":
            user = request.user
            profile = User.objects.get(username=username)
            follow = Follow(user=user)
            follow.save()
            if "unfollow" in request.POST:
                profile.followers.remove(user)
                follow.following.remove(profile)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('users', args=(username,)))
            elif "follow" in request.POST:
                follow.following.add(profile)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('users', args=(username,)))
```

This code yields in: "ValueError at /users/test
Cannot query "admin": Must be "Follow" instance." at the profile.followers.remove(user) line...

Playing with it in shell I found out (at least I think so) that the line under it (follow.following.remove(profile) - which by the way was there before I tried with the profile.followers.remove(user)) removes the profile from Follow model, but for some reason it is not by itself updated in the Users model (for followers) ???

Answer (score -1):

```
    from django.db import models
    
    # Create your models here.
    class User(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
        pwd = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    
    
    class Follow(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        another_user = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='another_user')
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.user.name
============================================================================
views.py

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import User, Follow
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    if 'user' in request.session:
        return render(request, 'index.html')
    else:
        return redirect('login')



def profile(request, user_name):
    user_obj = User.objects.get(name=user_name)
    session_user = User.objects.get(name=request.session['user'])
        session_following, create = Followers.objects.get_or_create(user=session_user)
    following, create = Followers.objects.get_or_create(user=session_user.id)
    check_user_followers = Followers.objects.filter(another_user=user_obj)

    is_followed = False
    if session_following.another_user.filter(name=user_name).exists() or following.another_user.filter(name=user_name).exists():
        is_followed=True
    else:
        is_followed=False
    param = {'user_obj': user_obj,'followers':check_user_followers, 'following': following,'is_followed':is_followed}
    if 'user' in request.session:
        return render(request, 'profile.html', param)
    else:
        return redirect('index')


def follow_user(request, user_name):
    other_user = User.objects.get(name=user_name)
    session_user = request.session['user']
    get_user = User.objects.get(name=session_user)
    check_follower = Followers.objects.get(user=get_user.id)
    is_followed = False
    if other_user.name != session_user:
        if check_follower.another_user.filter(name=other_user).exists():
            add_usr = Followers.objects.get(user=get_user)
            add_usr.another_user.remove(other_user)
            is_followed = False
            return redirect(f'/profile/{session_user}')
        else:
            add_usr = Followers.objects.get(user=get_user)
            add_usr.another_user.add(other_user)
            is_followed = True
            return redirect(f'/profile/{session_user}')

        return redirect(f'/profile/{session_user}')
    else:
        return redirect(f'/profile/{session_user}')
```

=============================================================================
[User This For Reference...Follow And Unfollw Logic](https://dev.to/madhubankhatri/follow-unfollow-system-using-django-simple-code-3785)